# React Multi Date Picker start date

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set the starting date of React Multi Date picker. Docs refrenced here: (https://shahabyazdi.github.io/react-multi-date-picker/min-&-max-date/)

I can see within the docs they've used

```
const [date, setDate] = useState("2020/12/04")
```

which set an active date to Dec. 2020. However, my dates are created from querying a list of dates, finding a minimum and storing it into a variable. The variable isn't defined when the useState is called, and I can't place the useState later due to hook rendering errors.

Is there another way to do this that I'm missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can init the date with the now(), and then with a useEffect [], set the state, the DatePicker is controlled by the state that will change

Comment: Thanks this was a good option!
I found out that there's a prop that can be passed called CurrentDate which takes a dateobject.